# unit test apache http client proxy 407

Tags: apache, junit4, apache-httpclient-4.x, http-proxy

I am trying to build a Junit/Integration test which needs to contact an external server. However, I cannot get past the proxy. I get a 407 blank authentication page error.

The Test setup I use

```
@Before
public void onSetUp() throws Exception {

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webproxy-nl.test.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "webproxy-nl.test.com");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");

    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "DOM\\lalal");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "tesssst");

    System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "DOM\\lalala");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "sldjsdkl");
}
```

Now all proxy settings are 100% correct. I added some nonProxyhosts as well.

I do not know what else I could configure here.

The return message is:

```
Http request failed: HTTP/1.1 407 BlankAuthenticationPage [status code 407]
```

**UPDATE**

I built a test stub which uses the CloseableHttpClient. This still gives me the http 407 error.

```
private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

public IDealHttpClientStub() {

    LOG.debug("Creating IDealHttpClientStub");

    System.setProperty("http.proxyHost", "webproxy-nl.test.com");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPort", "8080");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyHost", "webproxy-nl.test.com");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPort", "8080");

    System.setProperty("http.proxyUser", "DOM\\lalal");
    System.setProperty("http.proxyPassword", "tesssst");

    System.setProperty("https.proxyUser", "DOM\\lalala");
    System.setProperty("https.proxyPassword", "sldjsdkl");

    this.httpClient = HttpClients.custom().useSystemProperties().build();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have done it using the following impl.

```
private CloseableHttpClient httpClient;

public HttpClientStub() throws KeyManagementException, NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyStoreException {

    // Trust all certs
    SSLContext sslcontext = buildSSLContext();

    // Allow TLSv1 protocol only
    SSLConnectionSocketFactory sslsf = new SSLConnectionSocketFactory(sslcontext, new String[] { "TLSv1" }, null,
            SSLConnectionSocketFactory.ALLOW_ALL_HOSTNAME_VERIFIER);

    HttpHost proxy = new HttpHost("someproxy", 8080, "http");
    DefaultProxyRoutePlanner routePlanner = new DefaultProxyRoutePlanner(proxy);

    CredentialsProvider credsProvider = new BasicCredentialsProvider();

    credsProvider.setCredentials(
            new AuthScope("someproxy", 8080, AuthScope.ANY_HOST, "ntlm"), new NTCredentials(
                    "itsme", "xxxx", "", "MYDOMAIN"));

    this.httpClient = HttpClients.custom().setDefaultCredentialsProvider(credsProvider)
            .setRoutePlanner(routePlanner).setSSLSocketFactory(sslsf).build();

}

private static SSLContext buildSSLContext() throws NoSuchAlgorithmException, KeyManagementException,
        KeyStoreException {
    SSLContext sslcontext = SSLContexts.custom().setSecureRandom(new SecureRandom())
            .loadTrustMaterial(null, new TrustStrategy() {

                @Override
                public boolean isTrusted(java.security.cert.X509Certificate[] chain, String authType)
                        throws java.security.cert.CertificateException {                        
                    return true;
                }
            }).build();
    return sslcontext;
}
```

Then you have your proxy configured HTTP (Test) client.

Answer (score 0):

HttpClient does not make use of system properties unless explicitly configured to do so.

```
CloseableHttpClient client1 = HttpClients.createSystem();
CloseableHttpClient client2 = HttpClients.custom()
        .useSystemProperties()
        .build();
```

Comment: that does not work. I built the test around the CloseableHttpClient. still get the same 407 error. See my updated question

Comment: There can be numerous reasons for that. What auth schemes has the server been configured to support? What scheme does HC choose to authenticate? It is NTLM? It looks like the creds contain an NT domain.